# MySQL - Regexp for word boundary excluding underscore (connector punctuation)

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-8.0

I'm using regex word boundary \b, and I'm trying to match a *word* in the following sentence but the result is not what I need. Connector Punctuations (such as underscore) are not being considered as a word boundary

Sentence: `ab﹎cd_de_gf|ij|kl|mn|op_`

Regexp: `\\bkl\\b`

However, `de` is not getting matched.

I tried updating the regexp to use unicode connector punctuation (it's product requirement as we support CJK languages as well) but that isn't working.

Regexp: `(?<=\\b|[\p{Pc}])de(?=\\b|[\p{Pc}])`

What am i missing here?

Note: `(?<=\\b|_)de(?=\\b|_)` seems to work for underscores but i need the regex to work for all the connector punctuations.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Try: `(?<![[:alnum:]])de(?![[:alnum:]])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match any [connector punctuation characters](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pc/list.htm) you need `\p{Pc}`:

```
(?<=\\b|\\p{Pc})de(?=\\b|\\p{Pc})
```

NOTE: `\p{Pc}` can also be written as `[_\u203F\u2040\u2054\uFE33\uFE34\uFE4D-\uFE4F\uFF3F]` that matches all these 10 chars.

Comment: Oh Right !! In my original attempt i forgot to escape \p{Pc}. Thanks. It worked

Answer (score 3):

Based on the use case you have described you can simplify your regex to:

```bash
(?<![[:alnum:]])de(?![[:alnum:]])
```

instead of trying to match word boundaries, unicode punctuation characters etc.

This will match `de` if it not followed or preceded by any alpha-numeric character.